# C++: Help Creating unordered_map with User-Defined Hash/Equality

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++11, bind, unordered-map

I'm trying to create a std::unordered_map, using a user-defined hash function and equality predicate, for matrix rows of integral built-in types. I use std::bind, since I need the hashing and equality functors to work for variable ranges. How would I get the following code to compile and work as intended? I'm guessing that my mistake is towards the bottom of the listing, where I use std::bind and instantiate the std::unordered_map.

**Some clarifications:**

I can't use boost::hash_combine because I care about individual bits in the integers stored in the matrix row, so unless I create my own iterator, boost::hash_combine would combine whole integers, leading to erroneous results. Also, I need the hash and equality functors to work on ranges from 1 to ~200,000, so specifying the range in template parameters would not be a reasonable option.

```
template <class T,class F,class A>
struct row_hash_right : std::function<size_t(
        ublas::matrix_row<ublas::matrix<T,F,A>>,
        unsigned, unsigned)>
{
        typedef ublas::matrix_row<ublas::matrix<T,F,A>> row_type;

        // I want to use std::bind to bind the last two arguments.
        size_t operator()(row_type& a, unsigned s, unsigned e)
        {
                // Implementation of hash function.
        }
};

template <class T,class F,class A>
struct row_equal_right : std::function<bool(
        ublas::matrix_row<ublas::matrix<T,F,A>>,
        ublas::matrix_row<ublas::matrix<T,F,A>>,
        unsigned, unsigned)>
{
        typedef ublas::matrix_row<ublas::matrix<T,F,A>> row_type;

        bool operator()(row_type& a, row_type& b, unsigned s, unsigned e)
        {
                // Implementation of equality predicate.
        }
};

// Inside a function.
for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        for (unsigned j = i + 1; j < len; ++j) {
                auto x = std::bind(r_hash, _1, i, j);
                auto y = std::bind(r_equal, _1, _2, i, j);
                // ERROR:
                std::unordered_map<row_type, unsigned,
                        decltype(x), decltype(y)> m(256, x, y);
        }
}
```

**The error:**

Here is (what I think) the most important part of the error produced upon attempted compilation:

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:92:11: error: ‘std::pair<_T1,
>   _T2>::first’ has incomplete type
>       /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/fwd.hpp:73:11: error: declaration of ‘const struct
>   boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_row,
>   boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >’

If you want the see the whole thing, I've dumped it all here:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:40,
                 from src/test/read_test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘std::pair, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:486:12:   instantiated from ‘std::_Select1st, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int> >’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/hashtable_policy.h:789:20:   instantiated from ‘std::__detail::_Hash_code_base, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, std::pair, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int>, std::_Select1st, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int> >, std::_Bind, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > >(std::_Placeholder, std::_Placeholder, unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::_Bind, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > >(std::_Placeholder, unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/hashtable.h:105:11:   instantiated from ‘std::_Hashtable, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, std::pair, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int>, std::allocator, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int> >, std::_Select1st, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int> >, std::_Bind, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > >(std::_Placeholder, std::_Placeholder, unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::_Bind, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > >(std::_Placeholder, unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unordered_map.h:44:11:   instantiated from ‘std::__unordered_map, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int, std::_Bind, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > >(std::_Placeholder, unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::_Bind, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > >(std::_Placeholder, std::_Placeholder, unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::allocator, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int> >, false>’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unordered_map.h:256:11:   instantiated from ‘std::unordered_map, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int, std::_Bind, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > >(std::_Placeholder, unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::_Bind, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > >(std::_Placeholder, std::_Placeholder, unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::allocator, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >, unsigned int> > >’
./sal/alg/ehh.hpp:144:31:   instantiated from ‘sal::ehh_results sal::compute_ehh(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix&, unsigned int) [with FloatType = double, T = unsigned int, F = boost::numeric::ublas::basic_row_major, A = boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array >]’
src/test/read_test.cpp:11:51:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:92:11: error: ‘std::pair::first’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/fwd.hpp:73:11: error: declaration of ‘const struct boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_row, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array > > >’
```

Comment: Sorry, unescaped carat in the code ate up some of my words. I'm editing it now.

Comment: Ok, fixed; it should be clearer now.

Comment: I've appended the error towards the end of the answer.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed the error -- it was unrelated to std::bind, and had to do with needing to include some additional headers, since only the forward declarations were there. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hash a range of things, you need something like `hash_combine()`. I usually lift this function from Boost (surprisingly, it wasn't included in the standard!). Here's how I'd use it on `std::array`s, and I trust you can manipulate this into something to work on matrix rows:

```
#include <array>

template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t & seed, const T & v)
{
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

namespace std
{
    template<typename T, size_t N> struct hash<array<T, N>>
    {
        inline size_t operator()(const array<T, N> & a) const
        {
            size_t seed = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
            {
                ::hash_combine(seed, a[i]);
            }
            return seed;
        }
    };
}
```

(The above specialisation allows you to use `std::unordered_set<std::array<int, 10>>` etc.)

If the matrix rows don't come with an equality predicate, you could also add a specialization of `std::equal_to` for matrix rows.

Comment: I saw this in the documentation too, but I can't use this for matrix rows, because the actual values I care about are bits that are packed into integers (I'm storing dominant/recessive alleles). The actual implementation uses some bit manipulation, but I left it out for sake of brevity. An iterator would hash_combine entire integers, which would lead to some erroneous results, unless I create my own, which leads to various other issues.

Comment: Also, I need the same hash function to work on ranges from 1 to ~200000, so I'd need to use an approach that would work during runtime. Is what I want to do possible using std::bind?

Comment: @void-pointer: A runtime bound would be no problem, since you can just replace the template argument `N` by some appropriate `size()` call. I'm not sure about the bit packing; is it not possible to just treat every 32 bits as one integer?

Comment: Unfortunately, the runtime bound is not determined by the size of the array, but by the inner and outer counters in the loops at the bottom of the code listing. The hash function is called on the same array repeatedly, but operates on different ranges of the array each time. It is for a related reason that treating every 32 bits as one integer will not yield correct results (the offset for a particular call may not be a multiple of 32, in which case I'd have to start midway into an int).

Comment: Can you make a proxy class that represents those units that you want to consider as key values?

Comment: I suppose so, but the cost of creating even small proxy objects would build up quickly. I'm calling the hash/equality functors with rows in 120x200,000 matrices, and I'm building an unordered map several million times for each matrix (the data structure is a good match for the application; the computation is heavy). I thought that C++11 std::bind would make this much easier, but is it not possible to use it like I intend? I don't see why my code fails to compile.

Comment: Note that `bind` and `function` are heavy objects, potentially with type erasure and virtual dispatch. It's not clear that a light-weight proxy class would necessarily perform worse.

Comment: I did not know that -- I'll be sure to try using proxy classes if the code becomes too slow with std::bind and std::function.